# fs.createReadStream not always hits the close event

Tags: node.js, fs

I have the following piece of code in a Node JS script

```
fs.createReadStream(zipFile).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: outputPath }))
.on('close', function () {

    fs.exists(zipFile, function (exists) {
        if (exists) {
            fs.unlink(zipFile);
        }
    });

    resolve('Files unziped');
})
.on('error', function (res) {

    reject('Error encountered when unziping files');
});
```

However, not always hits the **.on('close'...)** event. I've tested the exact same file several times and only 20% of the times it unzip it. The rest of the times it does nothing...

Is it something that I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
It turned out that above code was totally fine. The issue was happening on my API call. When I called the API, the HTTP Response was provided through several chunks. Sometimes the chunks were small enough to send the full body at once. This were the cases where above code was working fine. The code was failing when there were more than one chunk to compose the full body and I did not compose the full body before calling the code to unzip the body.

Comment: Please disgregard this question. The reason why this is failing is because the zip file is not returned completely all the times by the service and this is causing the issue.. How should I proceed with this question no? Should I delete it?

Comment: You can either write your own answer that explains why it was failing in a complete enough way that it would be useful to people that read this in the future.  Or, you can use the "delete" link under your question and delete your question.  Your choice.  If you don't delete it, you should provide a good and complete answer that other's could benefit from.